# How to save dta file in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, stata

I used this code `df = df.to_dta("file_name.dta")` to save stata file.
It gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_dta'
```

Does anybody know what is the correct code to save a Stata .dta file in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method name is `.to_stata()`, not `.to_dta()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used df.to_stata("file_name.dta")， but it gives this error:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_stata'

Comment: Your `df` is clearly a `None`, not a dataframe. You have to investigate why.

Answer (score 1):

use the pandas `to_stata` DataFrame method.

```py
df.to_stata("file_name.dta")
```

Read the documentation: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_stata.html